# Spark structured streaming multithreading/multiple consumers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

I am working on a spark streaming application using spark structured streaming, confluent open source Kafka cluster and running spark job in AWS EMR. We have at-least 20+ Kafka topics producing data into individual Kafka topics in AVRO format and each topic has been partitioned between 3 to 4 partitions. I am reading all 20+ topics (comma separated topic values) using Spark `ReadStream`. Then filtering each message row from a resulting DataFrame, applying each message with correct Avro schema and writing the resulting `Dataset[T]` to S3 and Cassandra.

Few questions that I couldn't find answers for

1. Am I ok to use one `ReadStream` for all the topics? Will it be considered as one Spark Consumer for all the topics and partitions because I am only executing one 'spark-submit job' in EMR?
2. How does the spark application distribute processing across the partitions? Does spark read these topic/partitions in parallel using different executors or do I need to implement any multi-threading for each each partition?
3. Is it possible to scale to multiple consumers within a consumer group to parallelise?

Apologies for loads of questions and I think they all related. Appreciate any of your feedback or pointers where I can find documentation.

1. MyConfig

   ```
   val kafkaParams=  Map("kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> "topic1,topic2,topic3,topic4,topic5,
       "failOnDataLoss" -> param.fail_on_data_loss.toString,
       "subscribe" -> param.topics.toString,
       "startingOffsets" -> param.starting_offsets.toString,
       "kafka.security.protocol" -> param.kafka_security_protocol.toString,
       "kafka.ssl.truststore.location" -> param.kafka_ssl_truststore_location.toString,
       "kafka.ssl.truststore.password" -> param.kafka_ssl_truststore_password.toString
     )
   ```
2. ReadStream code

   ```
   val df = sparkSession.readStream
     .format("kafka")
     .options(kafkaParams)
     .load()
   ```
3. Then splitting Input Dataframe into multiple data frames using the 'topic column, and apply the Avro schema for each resulting dataframe.
4. Writing each `Dataset[T]` to different sinks like S3, Cassandra, etc...

Comment: Did you manage to get answers for your questions ?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I ok to use one ReadStream for all the topics?

Assuming all topics can use the same set of Kafka configurations, then sure. Might not be fault tolerant, though. For example, `failOnDataLoss` will cause the whole job to fail on a single topic failure.

> Will it be considered as one Spark Consumer for all the topics and partitions... Does spark read these topic/partitions in parallel using different executors?

Yes. And you can scale the number of Spark Executors up to the total sum of the partitions for all the topics.

> do I need to implement any multi-threading for each each partition?

Spark should be handling that for you.

> Is it possible to scale to multiple consumers within a consumer group to parallelise?

You should try to set a `group.id` property in your code, but having multiple executors is already creating a consumer group.

---

Unrelated to the question - What you are trying to do is already what **Kafka Connect** is meant for. Reading Kafka data into various data sources. S3 and Cassandra are already two existing implementations of plugins.